# Does curl --doh-url not accept ip address for dns servers and is the response just html?

Tags: curl, dns, libcurl, dns-over-https

When running the `curl --doh-url https://dns-server.example.com https://www.example.com` command, does curl --doh-url not take in an ip address? Can you not specify `https://127.0.0.1` or something along the lines of an ip address? Trying to do this with `libcurl` code as well, but would like to specify the frontend ip address of a gcp load balancer. Also is the response of a `curl --doh-url` command just html text? I only see the doh dns response when I have the -v verbose flag on. Was wondering if there was another flag that just shows the dns response. Many thanks!

Comment: If you just want to use a DOH transport to some resolver to see results, you should just use a DNS client using DOH, not an HTTP one. `curl` uses the DOH endpoint as an intermediate step to resolve the name of the website to connect to and then retrieve content and hence give you HTML back or whatever the server gave it. The DOH step is just an intermediate computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sure you can specify the DoH URL with an IP address. It requires that your DoH server has that IP in its certificate's subjectaltname though. (There's currently no `--doh-insecure` option to let you skip the cert check for DoH, possibly worked on in [this pull request](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/4579)).
2. No, a response of a `curl --doh-url` command is not just html text - that rather sounds like your server returns something bad  That command line option just controls how curl resolves the name used in the URL and curl will then transfer the URL just as normal. If the DoH lookup fails, it will of course not transfer any URL though.

Comment: Good to know about the ip address/doh server cert feature! For the `curl --doh-url` response, I'm running something like `curl --doh-url https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query https://www.google.com` and getting just html. However, when I do `curl -v --doh-url https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query https://www.google.com`. I see the `* DOH A: 216.58.194.196` and `* DOH AAAA: 2607:f8b0:4005:080a:0000:0000:0000:2004`. This is with the google dns server as well.

Comment: Daniel: I think the user wants to access the results of the DOH query and display it. It gets HTML because it just downloads some webpage, whose results is unrelated to how the hostname was resolved.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that's what I meant. Thank you for rephrasing!

Comment: The results of the name resolves are only ever shown in the verbose output, with or without `--doh-url`... We do however make a separate [doh](https://github.com/curl/doh) utility that shows the results of a DoH lookup.

Answer (score 0):

[curl's doh](https://github.com/curl/doh):  stand-alone application for DoH name resolves and lookups.

- Works with localhost / IP addresses.
- Shows complete DNS request / response in verbose mode `-v`.